# Suppress Node "Conditonal experts is an experimental feature"

Tags: node.js, dependencies, warnings, suppress-warnings

These days, several of my packages frequently spew out this message:

> (node:67849) ExperimentalWarning: Conditional exports is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time

How can I suppress it?

(I know what it means, roughly. It's coming from some dependency somewhere which I'm unlikely to be able to do anything about. I just want to tell Node to stop warning me about this particular issue.)

Comment: By the way, if you want to check which dependency is giving the warning, you can pass [`--trace-warnings`](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_trace_warnings) to node.

Comment: There also seems to be an active PR regarding this: https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/36137

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty sure you can't suppress individual warnings, but if you set `NODE_NO_WARNINGS` in the environment, it will suppress *all* warnings emitted by the node executable.